# Grouping records from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I've got two tables in MySql

> 1 (Staff): Id/Name/SecondName
>
> 2 (fee):
>   Id/StaffId/Date(yyyy-mm-dd)/HoursWorked(hh:mm)/fee(int)/workType

There is also a script adding records to fee table.

I'm trying to group data in php to create html table like:

```
Name, Second Name | January 2009 | 123:45 hours | 2100,00 USD
February 2009...
March 2009 ....
Next person... etc.
```

So generally I'm trying to sum fee and hours in specific month and print a report from database...

And I need some advice/help... What is the bast way to create table like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Not tested though...

```
SELECT s.Name, s.SecondName, CONCAT(DAYOFMONTH(f.Date),', ',YEAR(f.Date)), 
SUM  (f.HoursWorked), SUM(f.Fee)
FROM Staff s
JOIN Fee f ON f.StaffId = s.Id
GROUP BY s.Id, YEAR(f.Date), MONTH(f.Date)
```

Edit: Ofcourse you need to group on s.Id...

Comment: pls guyz somebody try to see the question `What is the bast way to create table like this?`

Comment: @Harish: I get your point :) Guess my brain skipped the "html" in "create html table"

Comment: Used with 'CONCAT(DAYOFMONTH(f.date),', ',YEAR(f.date)) as Date' from NickSoft example and it's working! Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this being perfect but it should definitely point you in the right direction. The AVG() function calls might be unnecessary.

```
SELECT 
Name,
SecondName,
SUM(fee.HoursWorked) as HoursWorked,
SUM(fee.fee) as fee,
YEAR(AVG(fee.Date)) as year,
MONTH(AVG(fee.Date)) as month
FROM Staff
JOIN fee ON staff.id = fee.staffid
ORDER BY fee.Date
GROUP BY staff.id, YEAR(fee.Date), MONTH(fee.Date)
```

Comment: pls guyz somebody try to see the question `What is the bast way to create table like this?`

Comment: hi not my question dude post it under the question

Answer (score 1):

That's not the best way, but if you want to do it with one query (it's easy to export to Excel):

```
SELECT
  s.Name,
  s.SecondName,
  DATE_FORMAT('%M %y', f.`Date`),
  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `HoursWorked` ) ) ) as TotalHours,
  sum(fee) AS TotalFee
FROM
  Staff AS s
  INNER JOIN fee AS f on s.id = f.StaffId
WHERE
  1
GROUP BY s.id, YEAR(f.`Date`), MONTH(f.`Date`)
```

You cal also query stuff:

```
// that's not a real function, just get all Staff into $staff
$staff = QueryRows(SELECT * FROM Staff);
```

and then query fee:

```
foreach($staff as $s){
  // use this query to query statistics
  SELECT * FROM fee
   WHERE StaffId = $s['id']
   GROUP BY StaffId, YEAR(f.`Date`), MONTH(f.`Date`)
}
```